# How can I include Twitter Bootstrap on Google Closure?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am working on [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/). How to include [Twitter Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: It is possible to modify closure elements using Twitter Bootstrap. See this link HERE -> [Google Closure Library UI styled with Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/urmuzov/closure-bootstrap)